# typescript arguments are not aligned (align)tslint(1)

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have the code

```
setTimeout(() => {
    const elementsInput: any = document.querySelectorAll('.Modal__headerEmailInput')
    elementsInput[0].focus()
    elementsInput[0].select()
}, 500
```

and tslint shows unexpected error `arguments are not aligned (align)tslint(1)`
What is a solution?

Answer (score 4):

After some time I figured out the non obvious (for me) solution:

```
setTimeout(
  () => {
    const elementsInput: any = document.querySelectorAll('.Modal__headerEmailInput')
    elementsInput[0].focus()
    elementsInput[0].select()
  },
  500,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on `Auto Fix On Save` in your code editor and it will handle such styling errors.

[image: VSCode example]

Answer (score 0):

another possible solution that disables this kind of error is to set the rule in the tslint file

"rules": {
"align": true
}

Answer (score 0):

A solution that work for me is to remove the "parameters" option in "align" rule section of the tslint.json file :

```
{
"extends": "tslint:recommended",
  "rules": {
    "align": {
      "options": [
        "parameters",  <----------- remove this line
        "statements"
      ]
    },
    ...,
```